# Understanding types in SystemC

Tags: c++, c, vhdl, systemc

I am a beginner in SystemC programming and there is one thing I noticed (looking in the SystemC official documentation): all types that I used to deal with in VHDL simulations have not been "ported" to SystemC.

I mean:

1. Consider `std_logic` in the VHDL standard library, there is not an equivalent in SystemC, however, in the SystemC documentation, I see many examples using `bool`.
2. Consider `std_logic_vector`, I see no equivalent in SystemC. Instead I can see, in many examples, usage of `sc_int`.

So I'm thinking that SystemC does not provide types in order to manage single bits or electric signals, but it provides a higher abstraction like in every common C/C++ applications.

Is it so or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Consider `std_logic` in the vhdl standard library, there is not an equivalent in SystemC, however, in the sysc documentation, I see many examples using `bool`.
> 2. Consider `std_logic_vector`, I see no equivalent in sysc. Instead I can see, in many examples, usage of `sc_int`.

It's not all that correct.

In SystemC you can use `sc_logic` and `sc_lv< T >` as `std_logic` and `std_logic_vector` respectively.

You can assign to `SC_LOGIC_0` or `SC_LOGIC_1` literals to `sc_logic`.

While you can use integer, hex or even 'bit-specific' literal to assign `sc_lv< T >` a value.

For example:

```
class some_device : sc_module
{
    sc_out< sc_lv<32> > address;
    sc_out< sc_logic > write_enable;

    SC_CTOR (some_device)
    {
        write_enable.initialize(SC_LOGIC_0);

        /* The following three lines do the same thing. 
         * Obviously you won't use all three at the same time... */
        address.initialize(0b00001111000011110000111100001111);
        address.initialize(0x0F0F0F0F);
        address.iniziatize(252645135);
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

It does have some types: `sc_int`, `sc_bv` (bitvector) etc.

Comment: They are provided, but one should add, that usually you indeed use SystemC for higher level modelling (protocolls/busses...). You can bitbang, but when I saw it, it was almost used to model/simulate on a slightly higher level (up to system level).